# Generate PDF using wkhtmltopdf.exe in c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating PDF using wkhtmltopdf.exe with below code.

```
 string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

        //string[] strarry = sPath.Split('/');
        //int lengh = strarry.Length;

  var pdfUrl = HtmlToPdf(pdfOutputLocation: "~/PDF/", outputFilenamePrefix: "DT", urls: new string[] { url });

        WebClient req = new WebClient();
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + pdfUrl.ToString().Substring(6) + "\"");
        byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(pdfUrl.ToString()));
        response.BinaryWrite(data);
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(pdfUrl.ToString()));
        response.End();
```

and

```
  public static string HtmlToPdf(string pdfOutputLocation, string outputFilenamePrefix, string[] urls,
 string[] options = null,
 string pdfHtmlToPdfExePath = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
    {
        string urlsSeparatedBySpaces = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Determine inputs
            if ((urls == null) || (urls.Length == 0))
                throw new Exception("No input URLs provided for HtmlToPdf");
            else
                urlsSeparatedBySpaces = String.Join(" ", urls); //Concatenate URLs

            string outputFolder = pdfOutputLocation;
            string outputFilename = outputFilenamePrefix + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-fff") + ".PDF"; // assemble destination PDF file name

            var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = pdfHtmlToPdfExePath,
                    Arguments = ((options == null) ? "" : String.Join(" ", options)) + " " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + " " + outputFilename,
                    UseShellExecute = false, // needs to be false in order to redirect output
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true, // redirect all 3, as it should be all 3 or none
                    WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(outputFolder)
                }
            };

            p.Start();

            // read the output here...
            var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var errorOutput = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            // ...then wait n milliseconds for exit (as after exit, it can't read the output)
            p.WaitForExit(60000);

            // read the exit code, close process
            int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
            p.Close();

            // if 0 or 2, it worked so return path of pdf
            if ((returnCode == 0) || (returnCode == 2))
                return outputFolder + outputFilename;
            else
                throw new Exception(errorOutput);



            //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //Response.AddHeader("content-length", theData.Length.ToString());
            //if (Request.QueryString["attachment"] != null)
            //    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExampleSite.pdf");
            //else
            //    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=ExampleSite.pdf");
            //Response.BinaryWrite(theData);
            //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem generating PDF from HTML, URLs: " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + ", outputFilename: " + outputFilenamePrefix, exc);
        }
    }
```

From above code the PDF is generating well.but I have two pages with the same URL for LogIn and Logout User.for example lets say www.xyz/pdf/brason .This same URL is used for LogIn and LogOut User but content will be different depending upon the User LogIn or Logout.

Now when I LogIn and try to generate the PDF using above code It always show me the content of Logout User Page.I am not sure how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if I understood correctly this is because wkhtmltopdf that is calling the page is not logged in. Wkhtmltopdf is kind of like creating a new incognito browser window without any login cookies/session so the page correctly thinks it's not logged in. You could maby check by debugging the request that the server gets when wkhtmltopdf calls it.

If this is the issue it can be difficult to solve. The solution depends on your login system and what you can do to go around the issue. If you can duplicate the login by using cookies you could maby set the login cookie yourself, see http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html#Page%20Options for more info on how to set cookie.

Another option would be to first create a request from a system that returns the logged in HTML and then save that to a file/stream and feed that file/stream to wkhtmltopdf (I'm guessing you could do that using HttpContext.Current.Request or something, I don't know).

Another workaround would be to create a duplicate page of the logged in page that looks exactly like the logged in page but really isn't - this page would just be used to fool wkhtmltopdf. Something like `www.xyz/pdf/brason?foolwkhtmltopdf=true` and then use that by calling something like `if(url.ToLower() == "www.xyz/pdf/brason") {url="www.xyz/pdf/brason?foolwkhtmltopdf=true"; }`. This could be a security risk depending on what information is shown though.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to save the output of the page before you convert to html. Because this calls the url directly and you are not signed in when it calls it convert to pdf the response gotten for its request
i had the same problem trying to convert a webform to pdf but with the values filled so i saved the response as html and the gave wkhtmltopdf the saved path as parameter

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        string htmlpath =Server.MapPath("~/htmloutput.html");
        if (File.Exists(htmlpath))
        {
            File.Delete(htmlpath);

        }  

        File.Create(htmlpath).Dispose();
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(htmlpath))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
            tw.Close();
        }

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf-page.pdf");
        PdfConvert.ConvertHtmlToPdf(new Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf.PdfDocument
        {
            Url = htmlpath,
            HeaderLeft = "[title]",
            HeaderRight = "[date] [time]",
            FooterCenter = "Page [page] of [topage]"

        }, new PdfOutput
        {

            OutputFilePath = path

        });
```

you can call this on a button click event. Only tested this on asp.net webforms. on asp.net mvc you need some other way to get the views html output